# function Mocking through Interface in golang

Tags: oop, go, interface, mocking, dependencies

I am trying to write a unit test code form following code which has 3 level of function calling as below:

The main function calls function A() and then function A calls function B() and C() depending upon some condition and function B calls function E() and F(), whereas function C calls function G() and H() on some condition.
The above like the code I have developed, Here I want to mock function E() and F() for function B, and G() and H() for function C. Please suggest me how to do it using interface.

Comment: Is this question meant to be complete?

Comment: Please post your code as simplified as possible but conveying the general idea. To post your code is required for most of practical questions. Keep it clear and clean.

Comment: There are a million ways to do what you're asking, depending on your functions in use. Please paste your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Abstract function type](https://play.golang.org/p/6FVSfYh2_C)

You can do it with dependency injection not using interfaces:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type a func(float64) float64

func A(arg float64) float64 {
    return math.Pow(arg, 2)
}

func mock(arg float64) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(arg)
}

func b(function a, arg float64) float64 {
    return function(arg)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(b(A, 2))
    fmt.Println(b(mock, 2))
}
```

#### Function is first class citizen in Go

> In programming language design, a first-class citizen (also type, object, entity, or value) in a given programming language is an entity which supports all the operations generally available to other entities.

It means you can pass function as argument among other possibilities. And of course you can declare an abstract type based on function with concrete interface **(Don't confuse with `interface` type)**

#### [Interface approach](https://play.golang.org/p/i3tGlqsSOl)

You can make compositions using your functions

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// Declare an interface type with dependencies
type HGer interface {
    H(float64) float64
    G(float64) float64
}

// Declare a dependent type with embedded interface
type Dependent struct {
    HGer
}

func (d *Dependent) B(arg float64) float64 {
    return d.H(arg) * d.G(arg)
}

// Implement the interface for an actual program
type ImplHGer struct{}

func (i *ImplHGer) H(arg float64) float64 {
    return math.Pow(arg, 2)
}

func (i *ImplHGer) G(arg float64) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(arg)
}

// Implement the interface for mock of dependencies
type MockHGer struct{}

func (i *MockHGer) H(arg float64) float64 {
    return float64(0)
}

func (i *MockHGer) G(arg float64) float64 {
    return float64(0)
}

func main() {
    // Use real implementation
    a := Dependent{new(ImplHGer)}
    // Use the mock
    b := Dependent{new(MockHGer)}
    fmt.Println(a.B(8)) // 181.01933598375618
    fmt.Println(b.B(8)) // 0
}
```

#### Embedding

> Including an anonymous field in a struct is known as embedding. In this case the Discount type is embedded in the PremiumDiscount type. All the methods of Discount are instantly available on the PremiumDiscount type. Furthermore those same methods can be hidden

It is possible to embed interface to struct to extend it's behavior or to be more specific - declare abstract dependency.

Comment: @Vicky, could you please add a code snippet and a play.go link to your question. Stackoverflow questions could and should be useful for others and people will be grateful to you. Keep your karma on bright side.